# Traceroute hits destination on fourth hop, then does 15 more

Tags: networking

Traceroute is showing that I hit my destination (147.21.65.42) on the fourth hop.  **So why does it do 15 more hops?**

From my location, the pipe to this server is an MPLS virtual private network.  I'm thinking that might be affecting what traceroute reports.

```
C:\>tracert example.com

Tracing route to example.com [147.21.65.42]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1     4 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  172.18.41.254
  2     8 ms    10 ms     8 ms  192.168.208.30
  3    14 ms     8 ms     7 ms  192.168.208.50
  4     8 ms     8 ms     8 ms  147.21.65.42
  5    16 ms    15 ms    16 ms  147.21.65.42
  6    55 ms    54 ms    55 ms  147.21.65.42
  7    55 ms    55 ms    55 ms  147.21.65.42
  8    55 ms    55 ms    54 ms  147.21.65.42
  9    55 ms    55 ms    55 ms  147.21.65.42
 10     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 11     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 12     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 13     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 14     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 15     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 16     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 17     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 18     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 19   143 ms   135 ms   119 ms  147.21.65.42

Trace complete.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

MPLS is well known to mangle Traceroute results: http://www.cisco.com/en/US/tech/tk436/tk428/technologies_tech_note09186a008020a42a.shtml